# how to add custom button in sale view

Tags: sales-order

I need to add 1 input box and custom button in sale view section under admin.which send emails to those email ids which is in input box.
How can I do this?

Comment: try this code:-_addButton 
$this->_addButton('button_id', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Some action'),
        'onclick'   => 'jsfunction(this.id)',
        'class'     => 'go'
    ), 0, 100, 'header');

Answer (score 1):

You can do this add below:

```
$this->_addButton('buttom_name', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ButtonLabel'),
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $SUbmitUrl . '\')',
            ));
```

to class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View`

then You need an  new action to `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` class where th form will be submited.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616499/magento-custom-order-attribute-admin-input-and-display

Since you are trying to add a text field and a submit button, I would suggest doing something like this

[image]

The above form information will be posted to a custom controller. You will need to modify this code slightly `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()` in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php in-order to resend the order email to new recipient